# Как проверить, что элемент std::vector найден и удален

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl, vector

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;

vec.emplace_back( "sse" );
vec.emplace_back( "avx" );
vec.emplace_back( "generic" );

vec.erase( std::remove( vec.begin(), vec.end(), "sse" ), vec.end() );
```

Comment: Да проще всего - или посмотреть, что `remove` возвращает, или сравнить размер вектора до и после...

Comment: Я не совсем корректный пример провёл.
Не всегда будет известно, что хранит вектор.

Comment: Принципиальная разница в чем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Словом, например:

```
auto it = remove(...);
if (it == vec.end()) 
{
    // Не удалено
}
else
{
    vec.erase(it,vec.end());
}
```

Еще вариант:

```
auto save = vec.size();
vec.erase( std::remove( vec.begin(), vec.end(), "sse" ), vec.end() );
if (vec.size() == save) 
{
    // Ничего не удалено
}
```

P.S. Ах да, чай, в 2018 году живем...

```
vector<string> vec{ "sse", "avx", "generic" };
if (auto it = remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(),"sse"); it != vec.end())
{
    vec.erase(it,vec.end());
    cout << "removed!\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решения.

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал так:

```
const std::string s = "sse";
auto first = std::remove( vec.begin(), vec.end(), s ), last = vec.end();
if (bool removed = last - first)  // ваш ответ
     vec.erase(first , last);
```